# Beautiful Soup insert_before and after not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have two Beautiful Soup tags and I'm trying to place one after the other so I'm using `insert_before` (and have also tried `insert_after` as another option). The function doesn't seem to have any effect on either tag. I would expect the result to be that, following the function call, object `new_p` includes `embed` after the existing `<p>` tag.

This shows the state of affairs (object types, effect of the function) in the terminal (inside a breakpoint) – any ideas?

```
ipdb> type(embed)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
ipdb> embed
<embed alt=" Refugee Tales)" caption=" Refugee Tales)" embedtype="image" format="fullwidth" id="1691"/>
ipdb> type(new_p)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
ipdb> new_p
<p> Refugee Tales walk (Photo: Refugee Tales)</p>
ipdb> type(html)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
ipdb> new_p in html
True
ipdb> embed in html
False
ipdb> new_p.insert_before(embed)
ipdb> embed in html
True
ipdb> new_p
<p> Refugee Tales walk (Photo: Refugee Tales)</p>
ipdb> embed
<embed alt=" Refugee Tales)" caption=" Refugee Tales)" embedtype="image" format="fullwidth" id="1691"/>
ipdb> new_p.insert_after(embed)
ipdb> new_p
<p> Refugee Tales walk (Photo: Refugee Tales)</p>
ipdb> embed
<embed alt=" Refugee Tales)" caption=" Refugee Tales)" embedtype="image" format="fullwidth" id="1691"/>
```

Name: beautifulsoup4
Version: 4.6.0

Comment: One after the other means that new_p should contain `<p> <embed/> </p>`  or `<p></p> <embed/>`?

Comment: I mean that the tags should be separate and one should open and close before the other opens `<embed></embed><p></p>`

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<p> Refugee Tales walk (Photo: Refugee Tales)</p>"
new_p = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")

embed=new_p.new_tag("embed",alt=" Refugee Tales)", caption=" Refugee Tales)", embedtype="image", format="fullwidth", id="1691")
```

To place the embed tag inside the p tag you need to:

```
new_p.p.append(embed)
```

To place the embed tag right after the p tag you need to:

```
new_p.p.insert_after(embed)
```

Comment: I want the second, but when I do what you suggest I get:

`*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert_after'`

Any other ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Notice that I use new_p as a BeautifulSoup object. Not as a Tag object. You are getting the error because new_p as a Tag object doesn't  contains p elements. It's a p element by itself. Also ou can't use insert_after method in a single tag because it doesn't have a parent tag.